# Make bounty Custom Message dialog box draggable

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, bounties, bounty-remarks

When placing a bounty, the Custom Message dialog box pops up, and is sometimes directly over the question.  There are times when writing the message that I want to refer to the question, but the box is not draggable.

Could we please make the Bounty Custom Message dialog box draggable?

### Flagging Dialog

[image: Moveable dialog]

### Bounty Dialog

[image: Non-moveable dialog]

<sub>(Images courtesy of [@Jehof](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133638/jehof))</sub>

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219589/147191. Why not take the images from there and add them to this, then close that as a dupe of this?

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen go ahead, you have the power!

Comment: @ShadowWizard. Thanks. Have done so. (Was busy earlier.)

Comment: Cheers @TRi now let's hold fingers this will get the attention of the team! :D

Comment: I would like to see this as well. I almost asked this same question but then found yours. The dialog box was covering part of the answer I was hoping to reference. +1!

Comment: This is still an issue: [Bounty popup doesn't float, but sticks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405829/4642212).