# Make Bounty-Dialog moveable

Tags: feature-request, bounty-dialog

Would it be possible to make the Bounty-Dialog (to start a bounty on a question) movable.

All other Dialogs, like Flagging or Closing, are movable.

**Flagging-Dialog**
[image: Moveable dialog]!

**Bounty-Dialog**
[image: Not moveable dialog]!

Comment: Wouldn't this create problems in touch screen devices?

Comment: @MIH what kind of problems?

Comment: @Stijn mobile devices have small screens, perhaps while scrolling up or down you will move the box instead, which will be inconvenience. Plus it might require additional Java script to check such conditions, and SE developers hate to complicate things.. this is my impression.

Comment: @MIH You'd have a point if this was a new feature, but since it's already possible to move other dialogs, I doubt this will cause mobile issues.

Comment: @MIH moving dialogs is nothing new on SE, cause other dialogs are moveable. I think it is only missing on the Bounty-Dialog

Comment: @Jehof you are right! I have never noticed it. good to know :)

Comment: I just tested it in my mobile phone (WP8), it doesn't really move and the screen scrolls instead, it rarely moves.

Comment: Hi @Jehof. I imported your images into the dupe, to improve it.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen yeah thanks. Well done.