# No notification about Investor Badge and it is missing under Achievements

Tags: support, badges, notifications

I have recently received the Investor badge for offering a bounty on question [Make bounty Custom Message dialog box draggable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170125/make-bounty-custom-message-dialog-box-draggable), but i have not got any notifications about it and it is missing under Achievements.

[image]

Comment: @hims056 so I´m a "Veteran user" as Shadow Wizard said and I do not get notified about this badge. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly...

Comment: this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133553/the-new-notification-system-didnt-notify-me-of-my-investor-badge?rq=1 is a better dupe